# React Hook useEffect multiple problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, use-effect

This is my first time using a useEffect hook. what its doing is reading the database to see if a value returns and if a value returns thats the userToken which is sign of an account so it signs you in. However, I have 2 problems. The Link name button doesnt automatically sign you in, instead you have to type another letter in the input box after to sign in. I tried fixing this by adding connectUser under writeUserData on line 49 but that just makes the site crash. My second problem is I cant display {userToken} on the page after bewing signed in. I recieve Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, set, child, get} from 'firebase/database';

export default function Username(props) {
        const [userName, setUsername] = useState('');
        const [userToken, setuserToken] = useState('')


        const clientCredentials = {
            apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
            databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
            projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
            storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
            messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
            appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        }
        const app = initializeApp(clientCredentials);
        const db = getDatabase();        
        const address = props.address;

        function writeUserData(userId, userN, ) {
            const reference = ref(db, 'users/' + userId);

            set(reference, {
                username: userN,
            });
        }

        const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

        function connectUser() {
            get(child(dbRef, `users/${address}`)).then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                setuserToken(snapshot.val());
            } else {
                console.log("No data available");
            }
            }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            });
        }

        const handleChange = (event) => setUsername(event.target.value);

        function handleClick(e) {
            writeUserData( address, userName);
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            connectUser()
        });

    while (userToken == '')
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <p className = "account-Info" >address: {address}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="form">
                    <h2 className='user-Create' > Username </h2>
                    <form id='set-User'>
                        <input id='username' className="user-Create" type='text' value={userName} onChange={handleChange} 
                        required minLength='3' maxLength='30' pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" title='only letters, numbers, and underscores.'/>
                        <button className='user-Create' type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Link Name</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </>
        );

    while (userToken)
        return (
            <p className = "account-Info" >hi user</p>
        );
}
```

Comment: I won't say you are clear about the button part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please do not use `while`. Instead, use `if`.

```
if (!Boolean(userToken)) return <something />;

// No need to give condition here
// If userToken is not false, this will return
return <main />;
```

Second, useEffect's dependency, according to what you wrote, which is

```
  useEffect(() => {
    connectUser();
  });
```

It means you execute `connectUser()` everytime any component update. Pass a dependency. If want no dependency, use `[]`, which means execute `connectUser()` only once when component mounts.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    connectUser();
  },[]);
```

Third, for `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username})`, if you get similar error in future, use `console.log()` to debug. In your case, `console.log(userToken)` and go see in console of your browser.

Fourth, if you are handling about authentication, did you consider using `firebase/auth`?

Comment: I dont want to sign in with firebase set params.  I did find one of the problems though and thats that firebase returns it as an object so I just need to take out the username

Answer (score 0):

For useEffect running multiple times, please pass in a dependency array. Check the react documentation on useEffect. You can start by giving an empty array as the second parameter to useEffect